# Modifying Jquery from displaying div to changing src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This was my initial code to make the div display on click. But now i wanted to change the div to iframe src.

```
<iframe src="change this link on click">
```

any one could enlight me how should I modify the script by changing the src not the tab ?

```
<ul class="tabpan">
    <li class="tab" id="tab_1">One</li>
    <li class="tab" id="tab_2">Two</li>
    <li class="tab" id="tab_3">Three</li>
</ul>



<div>
    <div class="tabbox tabbox_1">tab 1 content</div>
    <div class="tabbox tabbox_2">tab 2 content</div>
    <div class="tabbox tabbox_3">tab 3 content</div>
</div>


$(function () {
        $('.tabbox_1').show();
        $('.tab').click(function () {
            var tabid = $(this).attr('id').replace('tab_', '');
            $('.tab').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            if (!$('.tabbox_' + tabid).is(':visible')) {
                $('.tabbox').hide();
            }
            $('.tabbox_' + tabid).fadeIn();

        });

    });
```

Comment: You want your iframe src to change when you click on a tab?

Comment: you have not attempted in your posted code? isn't it?

Comment: "But now i wanted to change the it instead of div to iframe src" What does mean? Is there only one iframe?

Comment: @putvande i want the the ifram src to be changed when i click on the tab

Comment: suggestion is to readout the api about `.attr()` method.

Comment: `$('.tab').click(function () {
    $('iframe').attr('src','newSrc');
});`  But doesn't make much sense... I guess newSrc depends which tab has been clicked but you didn't provide enough info.And it is IFRAME, not ifram

Comment: @Jai have tried with the changing tab. but i wanted to make it changing the src instead

Comment: $( "iframe" ).attr( "src", "Chnage src" ); For reference please see this link http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: @A.Wolff im hesitating where do i put the newSrc link when i click on the list ? because it have few list.

Comment: @user2982110 i guess, you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/CQfRZ/  Using custom data-* attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line changes the src attribute of an iframe:

```
$('iframe').attr('src','new_url_goes_here');
```

Caution this changes all iframes, set your iframe with an ID let's say myIframe and use this instead:

```
$('#myIframe').attr('src','new_url_goes_here');
```

Put the code inside $('.tab').click function.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

In this example I have added the URLs into the "tabs" as custom attributes. You can reference these when trying to change the iframe's URL with the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method:

```
<ul class="tabpan">
    <li class="tab" data-url="http://jquery.com" id="tab_1">One</li>
    <li class="tab" data-url="http://jqueryui.com" id="tab_2">Two</li>
    <li class="tab" data-url="http://1and1.com" id="tab_3">Three</li>
</ul>

<iframe id="mainFrame" src="http://1and1.com"></iframe>
```

The jQuery simply pulls the URL attribute of the "tab" and changes the src of the iframe to that new URL:

```
$('.tabpan .tab').click(function(){
    src = $(this).attr('data-url');
    $('#mainFrame').attr('src', src);
});
```

Here is a working example: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wrxsti85/9USxc/)
Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 my suggestion, you can change `$(this).attr('data-url');` to `$(this).data('url');` because of http://jsperf.com/jquery-is-data-faster-than-attr-data

Comment: Very nice suggestion. I can't believe I never knew that. Thanks!

Comment: Should the src variable have the var keyword to avoid an implicit global variable?